# How to compute the dimension of a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$. How to compute the dimension of the vector space $V \otimes V \otimes \Lambda^2 V + V \otimes \Lambda^2 V \otimes V +  \Lambda^2 V \otimes V \otimes V$?

We have $\dim \Lambda^2 V = n(n-1)/2$ and $\dim V \otimes V \otimes \Lambda^2 V = n^3  (n-1)/2$. Similarly, the other two summands both have dimension $n^3 (n-1)/2$. But there are some intersection of the summands. What is the dimension of $V \otimes V \otimes \Lambda^2 V + V \otimes \Lambda^2 V \otimes V +  \Lambda^2 V \otimes V \otimes V$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there? Formally I'm not seeing it as pure tensors generate each space (pure tensors from each factor that is). So any element of the first factor are summands of things of the form $v\otimes w\otimes (u\wedge t)$ and no thing from any of the other factors has such a form.

Comment: How can there be intersections between the summands? Are you working in some larger space $U$ that contains what you call $V$ and $\Lambda^2V$ (Aside: if you want to typeset $\bigwedge^2 V$, the markup is "\bigwedge" not "\Lambda")?

Comment: @AdamHughes, $V \otimes \Lambda^2 V \otimes V \cap V \otimes V \otimes \Lambda^2 V = V \otimes \Lambda^3 V $.